# How to add another dimension to an einsum operation?

Tags: tensorflow, math, numpy-einsum, einsum

Suppose the `tensor` and `tensor1` are some calculated transformations of an input with the shapes provided in the code snippet. The einsum operation performs Einstein's summation to aggregate the results in a specific order.

```
import tensorflow as tf


tf.random.set_seed(0)


tensor = tf.random.uniform(shape=(2, 2, 2)) # Shape: (n_nodes, n_nodes, n_heads)
tensor1 = tf.random.uniform(shape=(2, 2, 2)) # Shape: (n_nodes, n_heads, n_units)

print(tensor)
print("-" * 50)
print(tensor1)
print("-" * 50)

einsum_tensor = tf.einsum('ijh, jhu -> ihu', tensor, tensor1) # Shape: (n_nodes, n_heads, n_units)

print(einsum_tensor)
```

How can I modify the einsum operation if I add the batch dimension? What is the correct way to do the same operation if there were a batch dimension meaning the new shapes would have been:

```
tensor shape: (batch_size, n_nodes, n_nodes, n_heads)
tensor1 shape: (batch_size, n_nodes, n_heads, n_units)
output shape: (batch_size, n_nodes, n_heads, n_units)
```

I thought of the modification below, but I don't know if it's true. What I understood from the original operation is that `j` and `h` are dummy indexes, and `i` and `u` are free indexes.

```
einsum_tensor = tf.einsum('bijh, bjhu -> bihu', tensor, tensor1)
```

This [guide](https://nn.labml.ai/graphs/gatv2/index.html) is the reference I am using (line 228). Note that I have changed `f` from the guide to `u`.

P.S: I asked this question on Artificial Intelligence Stack but they suggested that this is a programming question and should be asked here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dots operator like

```
tf.einsum('...ijh, ...jhu -> ...ihu', tensor, tensor1)
```

Check out the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum)!